# PHP MySQL WHERE Statement wont let me read more than one Row

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on a website using PHP and MySQL, but I have recently come across a really annoying problem that I can't seem to fix. I have a MySQL Query to read every post out of the database, but as soon as I add a "WHERE" Statement, it can only read ONE post, and when remove the WHERE statement, it can read them all.

The code I'm using is as follows:

Index.php

```
<?php

include 'includes/conn.php';

if(isset($_GET['p']) && isset($_GET['pg']))
{
    if(is_numeric($_GET['p'])){
        $id = $_GET['p'];
    }else{
        header("Location: /");
        exit();
    }
}else{
    $page = 1;
}

$post_count = $conn->query("SELECT Title FROM Posts WHERE Page='Home'");
$per_page = 10;
$pages = ceil($post_count->num_rows/$per_page);

if($page <= 0)
    $start = 0;
else
    $start = $page * $per_page - $per_page;

$prev = $page - 1;
$next = $page + 1;

$query = $conn->prepare("SELECT Title, Body FROM posts WHERE Page='Home' ORDER BY ID desc LIMIT $start, $per_page");
$query->execute();
$query->bind_result($title, $body);

while($query->fetch())
{
    echo '<div class="post">' .
    '<h2>' . nl2br($title) . '</h2>' .
    '<p>' . nl2br($body) . '</p><br /><br />' .
    '</div>';
}

if($prev > 0)
{
    $prevlink = "/?p=" . $prev;
?>

<center><a href="<?php echo $prevlink;?>">Previous</a></center>

<?php
}

if($page < $pages)
{
    $nextlink = "/?p=" . $next;
    echo '<center><a href="'.$nextlink.'">Next</a></center>';
}
?>
```

Conn.php:

```
<?php

$dbhost = "localhost";
$db = "mw";
$dbuser = "root";
$dbpass = "root";

$conn = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $db) or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());

?>
```

The Table layout is like this:

[image]

[image]

The Output is like this:

With WHERE: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0L8Bj.png

Without WHERE: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UxcqX.png

If anyone could point out my mistake - and tell me how to fix it - it would be great

Comment: What do you have in `$start, $per_page` variables ?

Comment: Can you show us a query with the variables interpolated?

Comment: Obvious questions are "are there multiple instances of a page called Home in the datacase?" and "do $start and $per_page hold the values you think they do?"

Comment: @GordonM The first is already answered by OP via pictures and the second posted by Shankar ;)

Comment: oh, um, sorry, I'll post the full code

Comment: `echo "SELECT Title, Body FROM posts WHERE Page='Home' ORDER BY ID desc LIMIT $start, $per_page";` what does this output

Comment: Added full code, I'll screenshot the output in a second.

Comment: put the line of code I mentioned right above your query. What does that `echo` output? You should output for example "SELECT Title, Body FROM posts WHERE Page='Home' ORDER BY ID desc LIMIT 0, 10" or similar.  What does it output? Also, take that line and use it directly in your database (like on command line or w/ phpmyadmin or whatever). Does it give you expected results?

Comment: Oh, By the way, I used links because I don't have enough reputation to add images.

Comment: @Crayon Violent what do you mean by output? And No, it doesn't come out as expected in the command line, it only had that one post.

Comment: @GordonM $start and $per_page are set to 0 and 10, yes, they hold the values I think they do.

Comment: @ProgrammingTurtle okay the goal here is to find out what values `$start` and `$per_page` actually have, when you create your query string. So I'm asking you to echo it out so you can see what the query string actually looks like.

Comment: and you say if you query the db directly, it still gives you just one result? Well then the only answer is that there's only one row that has a column Page="Home".  perhaps the 2nd column has leading/trailing whitespace? Try selecting and echoing out the row ID to narrow down which one isn't getting output

Comment: Aha! That was it! Please post this as an answer :) Even the simplest mistakes can sometimes be missed

Comment: The whitespace that is

Comment: /me shakes angry fist at whitespaces! :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add

```
echo "SELECT Title, Body FROM posts WHERE Page='Home' ORDER BY ID desc LIMIT $start, $per_page";
```

take the output and use it directly in your database (e.g. CLI or phpMyAdmin). If you query the db directly, and  still gives you just one result, then the only answer is that there's only one row that has a column Page="Home". perhaps the 2nd row's column has leading/trailing whitespace?

**edit**: and according to your comment, leading/trailing whitespace was exactly it!

Comment: *"leading/trailing whitespace"* - Wow, I probably never would have figured that one out. A well-deserved `+1` and then some ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- I deal with classified data all day long at my job.. stupid leading/trailing whitespace entered in from random people, causing data not to be bound to correct columns comes up a LOT for me, to where I've written various scripts to help me find them by replacing whitespace in data with visible markers, lol

Comment: Stripping the spaces at the source is something you do then, I take it. I don't deal with this at the same level as you do, however I do see a lot of questions on SO, which is one of my main sources for learning, oh... and Google of course. I'd say I'm an "ok" coder, I'm  resourceful; kinda of a "MacGyver" type 'o guy ;-) lol Good catch, once again!

Comment: @Fred-ii- well unfortunately, I do not have access to the environment where the data is entered in (it's 3rd party interfaces like Google Analytics and Adobe Marketing), so I can't change the code to trim the data in the first place :(. In those tools, users can enter in data in forms and the reports will show trimmed values, but they don't trim the stored data. So when someone attempts to reference data via an API.. well they have to know the *exact* value, whitespace and all.

Comment: Oh Lordie, yeah; I can see how that could make your job just that more difficult.